# Error 403 Restricted Client with Google Signin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I've setup firebase_auth and google_signin about 6 times, but in my latest app I must have forgotten a step.

firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3

When the Google Login page should appear I instead get a webpage that says 403 Error Restricted Client.  Further down it says This app is not yet configured to make OAuth requests.

1) I've update the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

2) I've added the section CFBundleURLTypes section to Info.plist file.

3) I've enabled Google auth in my Firebase project.

What did I forget?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In my case I forgot to set support e-mail address in Google Developers Console > API and service > certificate > OAuth consent screen [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) and this option also in your Firebase project setting. After set up everything is working.

Comment: This did indeed fix my problem.  However I'm not sure why.  I've never completed this step on other projects and I verified that one of my other working projects doesn't have an email address set in the consent screen config.  But still I very much appreciate that this project is working now.

Comment: I'm so confuse too.The project what am I doing now also is not my first project work with google login.And this spend me all day to search and try possible answer.Also if you are develop on android it will give you error `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)`

Comment: Thank you! I'm so frustrated right now. Nothing on the 403-page suggested anything about the support e-mail. Now I can finally move on with my project...

Comment: Worked for me after googling for 2  days now. I am wondering if there's an official document we can edit to help people out here.

Comment: you almost saved my life!

Comment: FYI, in most cases you can skip verification if you don't upload a logo.

Answer (score 3):

I set the support `e-mail` address and the `LOGO` in `Google` :

```
Developers Console > API and service > Credential > Oauth Consent Screen.
```

After this set up all is working.

Answer (score 2):

To fix a similar issue I had to add the email I am logged in with to google as a test user:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. On the top right ensure that your using the correct developer account
3. On the top left next to the words "Google Cloud Platform" ensure that you are on the correct project
4. In the search bar, look for "oauth consent screen" and click on it
5. Created a consent screen if you didn't before now
6. Under "Test users" click "+ADD USERS"
7. Add the email account(s) you will be testing with and save.

It should work now!

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with an angular project. The solution was indeed to set a support email address in the firebase console project settings under the general tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy, it didn't work even after I setting support email. But once I uploaded the logo image, it works.

Go to the link showing in error page, and set both logo and email.