# Nothing happen when clicking Google Sign-in button

Tags: swift, firebase, google-signin

**Update2:** Breakpoints don't seem to work because nothing stopped and have the same output

```
2019-05-25 21:12:10.264321+0700 dacna[6350:1182456]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-05-25 21:12:10.359445+0700 dacna[6350:1182465] 5.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50800000 started
2019-05-25 21:12:10.359560+0700 dacna[6350:1182465] 5.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see [URL][1])
2019-05-25 21:12:10.803643+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fc4de100950] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:10.804027+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fc4de100950] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:10.805877+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-25 21:12:10.805994+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-25 21:12:11.182929+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fc4de108110] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:11.183159+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fc4de108110] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:11.183561+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-25 21:12:11.183658+0700 dacna[6350:1182463] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-25 21:12:11.430492+0700 dacna[6350:1182464] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fc4dbc1aae0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:11.430687+0700 dacna[6350:1182464] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fc4dbc1aae0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-25 21:12:11.431169+0700 dacna[6350:1182464] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-25 21:12:11.431315+0700 dacna[6350:1182464] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
```

**Update1:** Forgot to mention that before this error happen, when the view is loaded, it automatically "do" the "sign-in" and I didn't know what's wrong as I was just following the document from Firebase.

At first, it was still working but there was an error 403 "Restricted Client".

I followed the first answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196172/error-403-restricted-client-with-google-signin-in-flutter) that I had to add an e-mail support and the problem was solved. But after I signed in with my email, the google page closed.

From then, nothing happen when I click the sign-in button

AppDelegate

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 14.0/255.0, blue: 74.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,annotation: [:])
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if let error = error {
            print("Having an error \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    }
```

ViewController

```swift
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
class LoginController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if let error = error {
            print("We have an error \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // DO IF ERROR HAPPENDS
                print("abc\(error)")
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            print("success")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: The question is a tad vague; did you add a breakpoint and step through the code to see where it's stopping? Did you examine the vars to see if they are set to what you expect? Do any of the print statements print?

Comment: @Jay I have just edited and none of these print statements print

Comment: ok, good start. You may have overlooked this statement in my prior comment *did you add a breakpoint and step through the code to see where it's stopping*. Do that troubleshooting step and update your question to include additional information.

Comment: Edited. I read and forgot your statement instantly somehow, sorry for that.

Comment: Breakpoints 'always' work. If it's not stopping at a breakpoint that indicates its not *getting* to that breakpoint so you need to add one earlier in the code. For example put one here `UINavigationBar.appearance` and start stepping through the code.

Comment: @Jay I tried breakpoint and was confused because it stopped right after the `viewDidLoad()`. I figured out that `sign` func is supposed to be in the AppDelegate and I have to SignOut before trying to SignIn again. I finally fixed. Thanks for your help