# Why do I get a 403 error when trying to login with Google?

Tags: flutter, webview, google-authentication

I have a Flutter application that uses webview.
It just opens the page of my site, but when I click on LOGIN WITH GOOGLE there is an error 403 in the app only.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196172/error-403-restricted-client-with-google-signin-in-flutter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 403 Restricted Client with Google Signin in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196172/error-403-restricted-client-with-google-signin-in-flutter)